# Simple question - Inverse of a derivative

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

I want the inverse of $f'(x)$ to exist. I believe a necessary and sufficient condition for the inverse to exist is the derivative to be monotone. Hence I conclude that I need $f''(x) >0 $ or $ f''(x) <0$ or the function is strictly convex or concave as a necessary and sufficient condition. Is that correct?

Second question, can I say something directly about my function $f(x)$ instead of saying something about the double derivative? I believe not.

Comment: $f(x) = x^3$ is strictly monotone on $\mathbb R$, but $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: I see. Would you like to add a necessary and sufficient condition for the inverse of a continuous function to exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can guess if the derivative $f(x)$ is invertible or not. $f''(x)>0$ or $f''(x)<0$ can be seen as "the curve is increasing at a faster and faster rate" or "decreasing faster and faster" respectively.

So for example the derivative of $f(x)=3x$ is not invertible because it is only increasing at a constant rate.

Another example the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ defined on the domain of all real is invertible because the curve has an increasing slope

But for $f(x)=x^3 - x$, the curve has a local min and a local max. The curve slope is first decreasing then increasing, so its derivative is not invertible.

So the criteria could be: if a curve has a local AND a local max, then derivative is not invertible. If the curve has a point of inflexion, which is equivalent to $f''(x)=0$ anyway, its derivative doesnt have an inverse.

Comment: What about the iff condition on Wikipedia at \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function} which says "A continuous function f is one-to-one (and hence invertible) if and only if it is either strictly increasing or decreasing (with no local maxima or minima)". ?

Comment: @bissi you are right generally, if the function (in your case the derivative) has a local max/min, then it should not be invertible. But look at $f(x)=tanx$, the graph is certainly "strictly increasing", as $sec^2 x=f'(x)$ is positive for all x. But the graph is discontinuous, and for any y value, I can find infinite x such that $tanx=y$. So it is not invertible if the domain of x is defined on the real line. The usual arctangent function is only an inverse when we restrict the domain of tangent to $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So maybe you will need "strictly increasing/decreasing AND continuous"